# phpMyAdmin - Insert random hex values

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to update my colour column to random hex value (without the #) through SQL tab in phpMyAdmin.

My colour column is just a char(6) utf8_unicode_ci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. Simply use `INSERT` with `RAND()`:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable SET yourcolumn=LPAD(HEX(ROUND(RAND()*16777215)),6,'0')
```

Change `255` above to match the highest value you need.

Comment: Can I force this to be 6 characters long?